# How can I apply a custom field validator to a model only when it is updated?

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a `models.DateTimeField` field that applies a custom validator to check the `datetime` can not be in the past:

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
   mydate = models.DateTimeField(validators=[no_past])
```

Validator:

```
def no_past(value):
    """
    Check the date and time are not in the past.
    """
    if not value:
        return
    now = timezone.now()
    now = now.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
    value = value.replace(second=0, microsecond=0) if value else None

    if value < now:
        raise ValidationError(
            'Date / time cannot be in the past.', code='no_past'
        )
```

Is there a way I can ensure this validator is only applied to new records created, and not when a record is updated?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think validators have a built-in way of doing this.

If I was faced with this problem, I would check the primary key (often called `Id`) field on the model. If it is `None` you are doing a create. If it is not `None`, then you are doing an update.